# Is it possible for an iOS app to programmatically know if the device has its date time set as automatic or manual?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I looked for NSDate, NSTimeZone, etc classes but none of them actually confirms if current data/Time setting is set as automatic or not. 
Is there any public api from iOS? I don't want to create a NTP client for this purpose atleast as of now. :)

Thanks in advance for you suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's automatically set?

Comment: @Devraj Yes! automatically set or is manually set

Comment: WHY do you need to know?

Comment: Basically, I have a timestamp for a certain event from an App-I, say at real world timeA, and I have to start a timer in App-II at timeB with [timeout = timeB - (timeA + timeOutTime)]. And in between timeA and timeB, if user changes the device clock, then it beats the whole purpose of timeout. Makes sense?

Comment: Even if the clock was set automatically how would you handle Timezones? I would recommend looking at timeIntervalSince1970 in NSDate and work all your dates back to the current timezone when you goto display the dates.

Comment: When the clock is set automatically, I assume timezone is also set automatically. 

About your solution, how is that going to help? I didn't understand it completely.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh : did you get any answer ?

Comment: there is a solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't a solution yet.